# Group By using columns containing specific values

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, group-by

I've been trying to build a view that groups and counts records containing specific values by year and month, but I'm stumped by this problem and hope someone might be able to lend me a hand.
I've a table called LNCARR that looks something like:

```
VerDate    | RootCauseCategory
----------------------------------------------------------------
2014-07-01 | Handling; Tooling; Training
2014-07-24 | Supplier; Handling; Tooling
2014-07-22 | Handling; Tooling; Training
2014-08-02 | Work Instructions; Workmanship; Quality System Implementation
2014-08-19 | Workmanship; Sampling Plan
```

I'd like to build a view something like below that shows the count of each RootCauseCategory occurrence per month:

```
Year  | Month  | RootCauseCategory                  | Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2014  | 07     | Handling                           | 3
2014  | 07     | Supplier                           | 1
2014  | 07     | Tooling                            | 3
2014  | 07     | Training                           | 2
2014  | 08     | Quality System Implementation      | 1
2014  | 08     | Sampling Plan                      | 1
2014  | 08     | Work Instructions                  | 1
2014  | 08     | Worksmanship                       | 2
```

For example, in 07-2014, the RootCauseCategory 'Tooling' is contained in 3 records so it gets a Count of 3.
I've gotten as far as the code below which will group and count the records by Year, Month, and entire RootCauseCategory (e.g. 2014 | 07 | Handling; Tooling; Training | 2), but I can't seem to figure out how to Group the rows by each occurrence of RootCauseCategory like above

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   ( SELECT    YEAR(VerDate) AS Year ,
                MONTH(VerDate) AS Month ,
                RootCauseCategory                   
      FROM dbo.LNCARR
    ) AS Result
GROUP BY Year, Month, Result.RootCauseCategory
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, month, Result.RootCauseCategory
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What `DBMS` do you use? Assuming `tsql`

Comment: google "tsql split function"

Comment: If you have the ability, I would skip the view altogether and change your database structure to match the second design you listed. Right now your initial table violates one of the core principles of Relational DB structure.. atomicity. No fields should contain more than a single piece of data and your RootCauseCategory field is capturing strings of multiple data elements.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Yes, T-SQL

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for the tip, currently looking into it. I'm rather new to SQL as a whole

Comment: @DanK I definitely agree with you and feel like this is an issue with how the table is structured, but I regrettably don't have that ability :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function to parse the string. then update the select with a Cross Apply.

```
select cast('2014-07-01' as date) as VerDate, cast('Handling; Tooling; Training' as varchar(200)) as RootCauseCategory
  into LNCARR

INSERT INTO [dbo].[LNCARR]
           ([VerDate]
           ,[RootCauseCategory])
     VALUES
           ('2014-07-24', 'Supplier; Handling; Tooling')
          ,('2014-07-22', 'Handling; Tooling; Training')
          ,('2014-08-02', 'Work Instructions; Workmanship; Quality System Implementation')
          ,('2014-08-19', 'Workmanship; Sampling Plan')

GO

Create Function ufnGetCategoy(@RCC varchar(200))
Returns @Category Table
(Category varchar(200))
as

Begin
    Declare @x int = 1
           ,@str varchar(200) = @RCC + ';'

    While @x < LEN(rtrim(@RCC))
    begin

    insert into @Category
      values (ltrim(rtrim(substring(@str, @x, charindex(';', @str, @x) - @x))))
    set @x = (charindex(';', @str, @x) + 1)
    end -- While

    Return

End; --Function ufnGetCategoy
go

SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   ( SELECT    YEAR(VerDate) AS Year ,
                MONTH(VerDate) AS Month ,
                Category                   
      FROM dbo.LNCARR
      cross apply dbo.ufnGetCategoy(RootCauseCategory)
    ) AS Result
GROUP BY Year, Month, Category
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, month, Category
```